# Structures and Strings in C

Tags: c, char

I started learning C and I wrote a short program implementing structures. For now, it only has a structure and a short function that is supposed to fill one of the structures (several are stored in an array). Program gets all the values (currently only for one structure to help me see what's going on) and the problem starts in main, in

```
printf("%s", tablica[0].nazwa);
```

Because program stops responding (no errors or warnings before).

If I put:

```
printf("%d", tablica[0].x);
```

It will print the value I put as x, so I know there is some problem with string in printf (but I can't figure out why). It's probably easy, but I'm just a beginner.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct struktura
{
    char *nazwa;
    double x, y, z;
};

int wczytaj(struct struktura tab[])
{
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i<1; i++)
        {
        printf("Podaj nazwe: ");
        scanf("%s", &tab[i].nazwa);
        printf("Podaj x: ");
        scanf("%i", &tab[i].x);
        printf("Podaj y: ");
        scanf("%i", &tab[i].y);
        printf("Podaj z: ");
        scanf("%i", &tab[i].z);
        };
    return 0;
}

int main(struct struktura* a)
{   int i;
    struct struktura tablica[6];
    int wyniki[6][6];
    wczytaj(tablica);
    printf("%s", tablica[0].nazwa);
}
```

Sorry for some names being in Polish, I can correct that, but I hope it doesn't blur the program).

Comment: Since `nazwa` is a `char *`, `&tab[i].nazwa` is a `char **`. Since you pass `scanf` the address you want it to store something in, you are asking it to store a string in the space of a pointer to a character. What if the string takes up more space than a pointer to a character takes? (Which it likely does.) Somewhere you have to allocate enough space to hold the string.

Comment: It looks like you don't ever allocate any space for nazwa (defined as a char *) so it is a null pointer.

Comment: For starters don't mess with `malloc`, but define it statically like `char nazwa[30]`

Comment: `int main(struct struktura* a)` that isn't the proper signature for `main()`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz But he does try to use it when the printf statement is executed.

Comment: ...and in `scanf("%s", &tab[i].nazwa);` which is supposed not to have the `&` and so would be dereferenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong format specifiers for `double` types in

```
scanf("%i", &tab[i].x);
printf("%d", tablica[0].x);
```

and others. They should be

```
scanf("%lf", &tab[i].x);
printf("%f", tablica[0].x);
```

Also this string input

```
scanf("%s", &tab[i].nazwa);
```

should lose the & ampersand like this

```
scanf("%s", tab[i].nazwa);
```

but even so `nazwa` has *no memory* allocated to it. As suggested in comments you could get going with a fixed array like

```
struct struktura
{
    char nazwa[30];
    double x, y, z;
};
```

You have a very unsual signature for `main`, which is usually

```
int main(void)
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```